# Get selected text on dropdown change event in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am trying to get the text of selected index in dropdown using knockout.js,

following is my HTML

```
<select name="" id="management" class="form-control" data-bind="value: ManagementCompanies,optionText:ManagementCompaniestxt">
<option value="0">---Select---</option>
<option value="1">abcd</option>
<option value="2">efgh</option>
</select>
```

following is my Model binding:

```
var FilterViewModel = {
 ManagementCompanies: ko.observable(''),
ManagementCompaniestxt:ko.observable('')
}
FilterViewModel.ManagementCompanies.subscribe(function (newValue) {

    alert(FilterViewModel.ManagementCompaniestxt());

});
ko.applyBindings(FilterViewModel, window.document.getElementById("SelectFilters"));
```

i have tried to bind using `Text` as well but didn't work.

how can i get selected text `abcd` in `subscribe event`?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit weird that you're trying to get data from your view to your viewmodel. Usually, your view is a *representation* of your viewmodel. It's better to have the data needed to render your `<select>` in your model, and use knockout's `options` data-bind to render it.

Here's how you can do this:

```js
var FilterViewModel = {
  ManagementCompanies: ko.observable(''),
  ManagementCompaniestxt: ko.observable(''),
  options: [
    { text: "---Select---", value: 0 },
    { text: "abcd", value: 1 },
    { text: "efgh", value: 2 }]
}

FilterViewModel.ManagementCompanies.subscribe(function(newValue) {
  console.log(newValue.text);
});

ko.applyBindings(FilterViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="value: ManagementCompanies, 
                   options:options, 
                   optionsText: 'text'">
</select>
```

Comment: Yeah, and it would translate into list of options in HTML, so this is the best way :D